# One-to-Many join table extra-column?

Tags: hibernate, orm, one-to-many

Assume you have two entities: `User` and `Decision`.

You want to associate a list of users to each decision, so you add a `@OneToMany` relation in the `Decision` class.

This will create a join table which could look something like

```
|decisionId| userId   |
|----------|--------- |
|1         | 2        |
|1         | 3        |
|1         | 5        |
|1         | 6        |
|1         | 8        |
|1         | 9        |
|2         | 1        |
|2         | 3        |
|2         | 7        |
|3         | 5        |
|3         | 7        |
|3         | 8        |
|3         | 9        |
```

Here comes the tricky thing. I need to associate a "new" value to each association above. This is, for every user in the list of users of a decision, I want to store another value (a double in this case) with the "weight" of that `User` in that `Decision`.

As a first approach, I was creating a new class `Voter` which had only a `User` and a `weight` properties, and add a `@OneToMany` relation to `Voter` instead of `User` in the `Decision` class.

However, this would result in two tables: The join table, and a `Voter` entities table.

```
|decisionId| voterId  |               |voterId  | userId  |  weight
|----------|--------- |               |---------|---------|----------
|1         | 1        |               |1        | 2       | 10.2
|1         | 2        |               |2        | 3       | 2.7
|1         | 3        |               |3        | 5       | 8.1
|1         | 4        |               |4        | 6       | 20.1
|1         | 5        |               |5        | 8       | 15.6
|1         | 6        |               |6        | 9       | 11.2
|2         | 7        |       and     |7        | 1       | 52.6
|2         | 8        |               |8        | 3       | 84.2
|2         | 9        |               |9        | 7       | 84.3
|3         | 10       |               |10       | 5       | 12.2
|3         | 11       |               |11       | 7       | 54.6
|3         | 12       |               |12       | 8       | 74.6
|3         | 13       |               |13       | 9       | 96.3
```

But.. it would have been "so easy" to just add a column to the join table of the first case... But then the "weight" data would be floating in an unknown dimension as it wouldn't be associated to any Java class...

Do this makes sense? is there a best practice to do this with hibernate?

Comment: good question, I am trying to do a similar thing. all the examples of using a Join Table seem to be for ManyToMany relationships... will report back here if I find something that works.